# java servlet remove session

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have tried to remove session but I couldn't do that.

```
private boolean removeSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean success = false;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        request.getSession(true).invalidate();
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: what is your requirement?

Answer (score 5):

What you are saying with this code is if there is a session get it. Then if there is a session create a new one and invalidate the new one.  You never invalidate the session that is already there.

just use

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```